# Are there differences between the races?

Tags: star-command

There a lot of different races in Star Command, but I don't see any obvious differences in them so far. It would make sense that Midorians are better at science jobs, but I never see this indicated anywhere or notice a difference in gameplay.

Are there actually any differences between races, or is it just cosmetic only?

Comment: I haven't been able to dig up official sources for the current build, but in earlier stages of development, it was made known that the devs didn't want species perks lest people feel forced to choose certain species if crew members for their perks. Enemy units get species related special abilities as I'm sure you are aware, but that's about the extent of any non-cosmetic distinction, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Star Command wikia page on Races](http://starcommand.wikia.com/wiki/Races), some races have innate special abilities.

For example, [Cortex](http://starcommand.wikia.com/wiki/Cortex) units have the Knockback ability, while the [Antorians](http://starcommand.wikia.com/wiki/Antorians) have Knockback, Fire, and Explosion.

Answer (score 0):

No differences aside from cosmetic ones.